# sqlite table consider any String as correct username and pwd

Tags: android, sqlite

** register table consider any String as valid**

**login class**

> there is a register table  and there are fields FirstName,LastName and Password i check edittext values to the register table ....  but it returns true for any String.....

```
 package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class login extends Activity{

    EditText e1,e2;
    Button b1;

    DBHandler handler=new DBHandler(this);
    //SQLiteDatabase db=handler.getWritableDatabase();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e_l_fnm);
        e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e_l_lnm);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_login);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String fname=e1.getText().toString();
                String pwd=e2.getText().toString();
                if(fname.equals("") || pwd.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fields are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    handler.login(fname, pwd);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "login successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                  Intent i=new Intent(login.this,home.class);
//                  startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**login method (DBHandler class)**

```
public boolean login(String fname,String pwd)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_REGISTER + " WHERE FirstName=? AND Password=?", new String[]{fname,pwd});
        if(c!=null)
        {
            if(c.getCount()<0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Your `login()` method most likely *never* returns `false`. As is `false` can only be returned when `getCount()` is (strictly) less than zero, which does not make sense. You probably wanted `<= 0`. You also never check the return value from `login()` so why do you expect the result to make any difference? Also wrt. to robustness: You succeed the login when `rawQuery()` returns `null` (which it never should, but nonetheless). Program defensively.

Comment: thanks but login method i by mistakenly i was just changing in login method to solve problem and put here without changing it...but thanks for answering......

Comment: In this case, post the actually code you are using. Because if the code in your question code is different from the code you are using in your app, it is only possible to guess what goes wrong in your app.

Comment: Yes Right..... nd ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validate `handler.login` method call result using `if-else` if condition is `true` then start next step otherwise show alert message for "Invalid Login" :

```
if(handler.login(fname, pwd)){
  // use login successful
}else{
  // login failed 
}
```

Comment: thanks succeed ..but  there is no diff in you suggestion and in my implementation i just had put it in else part nd ur suggest was to put it in if part........  plz elaborate

Comment: @farhan: here `if(fname.equals("") || pwd.equals(""))` you are checking input values by user for null or empty but for login calling `handler.login(fname, pwd)` method which will tell you is login is success or not . both condition is required . so add my suggested code in else block of current code